# Issues with classes and static variables

Tags: c++, class, static

I am having troubles wrapping my head around the use of static class variables, and what exactly to include within the main file, as opposed to the function file. When I try to compile my code I get a huge number of errors.

The question provided requires me to create a static ID variable that is incremented by each new animal (e.g. Elephant and Cheetah), so elephant would display ID 1 and cheetah ID 2. I know my animal.h  file is correctly formatted, but I am unsure about the main and animal.cpp files.

Could someone please correct any issues that are present within my code? Thanks!

**animal.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

class animal{
public:
animal();
animal(string aSpecies);            //Animals are allocated a unique ID on 
 //creation,
                                    //the first animal has ID 1, second is 2 
 //and so on
void set_name(string aName);        //Change the animals name
string get_species();
string get_name();
std::string name;
std::string species;
int get_ID();                       //The animals unique ID

static int currentID;                   //The next ID number to give out
~animal();
};

#endif //ANIMAL_H
```

**animal.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "animal.h"

using namespace std;


//static ID variable
int animal::currentID = 0 ;


//Default animal constructor implementation
animal::animal(){
  name = "?";
  currentID++;
}

animal::animal(string aSpecies){
  species = aSpecies;
}

void animal::set_name(string aName){
  name = aName;

}

std::string animal::get_species(){
  return species;
}

std::string animal::get_name(){
  return name;
}
```

**main-1-1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "animal.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

animal Elephant;
animal Cheetah;

Elephant.set_name("Katrina");
Cheetah.set_name("Alex");

cout << Elephant.get_name() << " " << animal::currentID <<endl;
cout << Cheetah.get_name() << " " << animal::currentID << endl;


return 0;
};
```

Comment: the new operator returns a pointer to an object, not the actual object.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to make corrections that are pointed out by answers, since then the answers no longer make sense. And if all issues are fixed, your question is no longer asking any useful question.

Comment: Please properly indent your code before posting it.   You'll get more help if people don't have to struggle through your code to see what's going on.

Comment: Please ask a single specific question at a time complete with MINIMAL reproduction code and specific error messages.  If you need to ask multiple questions, that is fine.  But "Please help with everything wrong with my code" is not an appropriate question for stack overflow.  [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some syntax to correct

The static member variable has the classes namespace, so in `main` you also have to call it with

```
animal::currentID
```

Then, `new` returns a pointer, so `Elephant` and `Cheetah` should be declared like

```
animal* Elephant;
animal* Cheetah;
Elephant = new animal("Elephant");
Cheetah = new animal("Cheetah");
```

However, there is no reason to use pointers here, just do

```
animal Elephant("Elephant");
animal Cheetah("Cheetah");
```

Also, the default constructor has not been defined in the classes body, you have to add

```
animal();
```

to the class declaration.

The members `name` and `species` are missing in the class body, too so make sure to add

```
private:
std::string name, species;
```

to the class body

There is no `<<` operator for `animal` yet, so the output does not know what to do. You can add them to the class or output only the `species` member of the `animal`. Overloading the operator would look like this

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, animal const &A){
  os << "The animal " << A.name << " is of species " << A.species
     << " and has ID " << A.myID;
};
```

And you typically declare it as a friend non-member, so add

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, animal const &A);
```

to the class body, this allows the operator to access the private members of `animal`. Note that this requires `<iostream>` for `animal` to work. You can then do

```
std::cout << Cheetah << std::endl;
```

And it will print the description of `Cheetah`.

Some further advice:

Having `using namespace` in a header file is a dangerous thing, it might bring things into scope that you are not aware of.

From the code you posted, `currentID` has no reason to be a member of `animal`, it can just be a local variable in `main`. If you want to keep track automatically, you can add a non-`static` member `myID` and increment the ID upon construction like this

```
class animal{
public:
   animal::animal():myID(++currentID){};
private:
   static int currentID;
   int myID`
};
int animal::currentID = 0;
```

Comment: By default constructor being defined in the classes body, do you mean add :
animal(); and ~animal(); to the animal.h class?

Comment: The constructor `animal();` is enough, as you do not declare a destructor, the default one will be generated automatically.

Comment: I added a description of how to overload the `operator<<`

Comment: Hmm okay. I keep trying to compile but I Get the error "undefined reference to ' animal::~animal()' . What have I done wrong? Ill edit the code above and show you the updated version.

Comment: Ah, I see, I must have overlooked that. Essentially, defining `~animal();` in the class body requires the destructor to be declared, too. As there is nothing to destruct, either remove that line or declare it inline as `~animal(){};`

Comment: That fixed that issue thankyou!! It does compile now, however the current ID of each animal does not increment and they both stay on 2, even though I have included currentID++ within the function file. Why is this? How could I also provide the species of each animal along with the name using the cout within the main? I have edited to the new updated code.

Comment: `currentID` is static, so all animals have the same value for that. It is increased in the constructor, which happens when defining `Elephant` and `Cheetah`, both before the output. By the time you reach the output, it already is `2` for both instances. Using an additional non-static member as I added it to the answer helps here.

Comment: About the output: It is most convenient to overload the `operator<<` for `animal`, I added a description of that to the answer. You can then essentially output anything about the animal in the overloaded operator, including `name`, `species` and `myID`, as described in the answer

Comment: Ah got it all to work. Thankyou so much for your help Kai I appreciate it!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are declaring the static variable correctly and setting it to zero.  However, you need to increment it in the constructors (`animal::animal`).

The other issue is that you are using the `new` keyword to allocate two animals on the heap, but then you are assigning the pointers to `animal` objects.  Here are two ways you could handle this instead instead:

```
animal Elephant("Elephant");    // Not on the heap
```

*OR*

```
animal *Elephant = new animal("Elephant");   // Elephant is a pointer to an object on the heap
```

Another thing, `std::cout` has no way of knowing how to print these objects.  Instead of printing them directly, you should call one of your `get_` functions:

```
cout << "The animal " << Elephant.get_species() << ... ;
```

Finally, if you want to be able to access the ids of the animals, you need to store the ids as member variables and use the static id variable as an incremented to ensure that every animal has a unique, consecutive id.